# Run-Time Error '424': Object Required on attempting to change definition of object, Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

As it stands now I have it written up where the code creates a file in the folder that the original file exists in. Once the file is created, I want to have it where wbBK2 is defined as the file that was just created. I figured using the same code to create the file, minus the SaveAs option would work, but it seems that it doesn't like the object.

Is there a reason why? For all intended purposes it should be pointing directly at the file, but it seems to not agree... can someone see the mistake I've made?

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenOrderReportExport()

    Dim wsJL As Worksheet   'Jobs List
    Dim wsPOT As Worksheet  'PO Tracking
    Dim wsTNO As Worksheet  'Tel-Nexx OOR
    Dim wbBK2 As Workbook   'New Workbook
    Dim wsWS1 As Worksheet  'Sheet1
    Dim wsWS2 As Worksheet  'Sheet2
    Dim wsWS3 As Worksheet  'Sheet3
    Dim CurrentFile As String, NewFileType As String, NewFile As String, Dir As String


    Set wsJL = Sheets("Jobs List")      'Jobs List
    Set wsPOT = Sheets("PO Tracking")   'PO Tracking
    Set wsTNO = Sheets("Tel-Nexx OOR")  'Tel-Nexx OOR
    Set wbBK2 = Workbooks.Add           'New Workbook
    Set wsWS1 = wbBK2.Sheets("Sheet1")  'Sheet1
    Set wsWS2 = wbBK2.Sheets("Sheet2")  'Sheet2
    Set wsWS3 = wbBK2.Sheets("Sheet3")  'Sheet3

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False    ' Prevents screen refreshing.
        CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        NewFileType = "Excel Files 2007 (*.xlsx)"
        Dir = ThisWorkbook.path
        wbBK2.SaveAs Dir & Application.PathSeparator & "Open Order Report -" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsx"
        Set wbBK2 = Dir & Application.PathSeparator & "Open Order Report -" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsx"

        MsgBox wbBK2
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need the line `Set wbBK2 = Dir....`. It is already set. Comment that line and change `MsgBox wbBK2` to `MsgBox wbBK2.Name` to check.

Comment: Seriously? I hate overanalyzing things like this... thanks.

Comment: You have already set it by saying `Set wbBK2 = Workbooks.Add` Now even after you save it, the object will remain live till the time you destroy it...

Comment: `Dir` is a built-in VBA command and it's best practice not to have variables with identical names to built-in commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already hinted at in the comments `Dir & Application.PathSeparator & "Open Order Report -" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsx"` does not create an object. That code returns a string, which is an ordinary data type in VBA.

The error occurs when you use `set wbBK2 =` the code above, because set requires an object to reference.

As an aside, as Siddharth Rout already pointed out, you actually correctly created the reference to the work book with this line `Set wbBK2 = Workbooks.Add` so a further set line is unnecessary.